# Office Web Addin - Can i change task pane header dynamically?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have created the Office Web Word Addin solution and specified Display name in manifest.xml like below

```
 <DisplayName DefaultValue="My Office Addin" />
```

[image]

Displayname default value displayed in Taskpane header. But i need to change this Display name based on screens(Ex. Page1.html, Page 1). Is it possible in office web addin?.

Answer (score 3):

I know, I am late but as an answer, although TaskPane's title can not be changed dynamically but title can be differ from what we set for "DisplayName"

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
  <TaskpaneId>TaskPane1</TaskpaneId>
  <SourceLocation resid="yoururl" />
  <Title resid="shortstringresid"/>
 </Action>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you mention correctly the `DisplayName` comes from add-in manifest and **cannot** be dynamically changed. I would suggest to use Web page aria to display sub-headers required for particular page.

Comment: Ok. Thank you.. @Slava Ivanov